# EmberJS pre2 put handlebar templates on wrong place

Tags: ember.js

I've try to update EmberJS from pre1 to pre2 on my web-app but I notice it put all handlebar templates as the last body elements, and sometime not at all.

I've [create a repro](http://emberjs-pre2-bug.staticloud.com/) with the starter-kit with simple modification of putting div before and after the template to show the template will be added in the wrong place.
Run this same page with pre1 and it all works just fine.

*index.html*

....

```
<body>
  <div>this is before the template</div>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Hello from Ember.js</h1>
  </script>
  <div>this is after the template</div>
```

....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text/x-handlebars script tag defines a Handlebar template, and its irrelevant where you place it in the page (in the head, anywhere in the body).

In your code above you define the template for the `ApplicationView`. Since you use a router, ember automatically creates `ApplicationView` and **appends** it to the root element of your Ember app. By default, the `rootElement` is the body:

```
App.ApplicationView.create().appendTo(rootElement) // default rootElement = 'body'
```

and the `appendTo` method uses jQuery [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
this.$().appendTo(target)
```

Therefore if you want to control where the `applicationView` is inserted you need to set the `rootElement` in the App instance, like so:

```
  window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#insert_my_app_here'
  });
```

...

```
  <body>
    <div>this is before the template</div>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <h1>Hello from Ember.js</h1>
    </script>
    <div id="insert_my_app_here"></div>
    <div>this is after the template</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. First this breaks behavior of pre1 code which did insert the handlebar templates in the place they were define. Second, how can I insert different handlebar template in different places? I'm using EmberJS because of it ability to be "plug and play" into exist HTML application without the need to rewrite it all over.

Comment: Not sure how it behaved before, as I never used inline handlebars templates (I use separate handlebar files). However, if you want to insert non-nested templates in your HTML, use `appendTo` (see ember.js API docs). You just have to make sure that you don't appendTo inside an Ember.View, in which case Ember complains `You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead`.

Comment: It was very easy to simple put the template in the place I needed it and not have to write any javascript code for it, it's a shame it's gone :(