# Ember.js View and params

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.js route like this:

```
this.route 'doc', path: '/docs/:doc'
```

And I need to set the template based on the `:doc` param. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: what does the model look like for this route?

Comment: There isn't a model, so to speak. It's just for loading a template. Kinda like a static HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this:

1. Set the desired templateName into your context/model in the property "templateName".
2. In the View for your route access the context of the View (= your model) and read the property and set it as templateName of the View.

---

```
App.DocView = Ember.View.extend({
    render : function(buffer){
      var context = this.get("context.content");
      this.set("templateName", context);
      this._super(buffer);
    }
});
```

Link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/DQ8gS/2/

Comment: Thanks, but `context` is `null` in my view for some reason. Help?

Comment: Is the property controller also null? Or post a fiddle and we will fix it fast :-)

Comment: Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdirwin/jVwng/). I'm just starting with Ember.js so I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Check out my fiddle. I realized that one has to override the render method to realize your requirement. In the fiddle you will see, that you can switch between two templates with the same View.

Comment: Thanks! I've got the templates loading now, but their contents aren't being put in the correct place in the main HTML. I have a `div` with an ID of `#content` that I'd like them to placed into. How might I achieve that?

Comment: This can be achieved by using outlets. I updated the fiddle once more to show how to implement it. If there are more questions, you should probably go trough some tutortials about the use of Routes and Outlets.

Comment: I got the content to appear where I wanted using [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13326004/613444). Thanks again for your help!